# Error while building apk from kivy app first time with buildozer

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, cython, buildozer

I am on Ubuntu16.04 inside VirtualBox in Windows 10. I am creating android package for an app made in kivy. I am using Python3.7.12.

In terminal when I ran `buildozer android debug` , I got the following error:

```
[INFO]:    STDOUT (last 20 lines of 315):
                            curexc_value    
/home/ve111/Kivy/Clock/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/cpython/pystate.h:80:15: note:   
      'curexc_value' declared here  
    PyObject *curexc_value; 
              ^ 
jnius/jnius.c:54665:22: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts';
      did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?  
    tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback; 
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~  
                     curexc_traceback   
/home/ve111/Kivy/Clock/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/cpython/pystate.h:81:15: note:   
      'curexc_traceback' declared here  
    PyObject *curexc_traceback; 
              ^ 
jnius/jnius.c:54666:13: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'   
    tstate->exc_type = *type;   
    ~~~~~~  ^   
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=] 
17 warnings and 20 errors generated.    
error: command '/home/ve111/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
[INFO]:    STDERR:
    
[INFO]:    ENV:
export CFLAGS='-target aarch64-linux-android21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -I/home/ve111/Kivy/Clock/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include'
export CXXFLAGS='-target aarch64-linux-android21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a'
export CPPFLAGS='-DANDROID -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -I/home/ve111/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android -I/home/ve111/Kivy/Clock/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/time_tars/arm64-v8a/include/python3.8'
export LDFLAGS='  -L/home/ve111/Kivy/Clock/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/libs_collections/time_tars/arm64-v8a -L/home/ve111/Kivy/Clock/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/android-build -lpython3.8 -L/home/ve111/Kivy/Clock/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/libs_collections/time_tars/arm64-v8a -L/home/ve111/Kivy/Clock/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/libs_collections/time_tars  -L/home/ve111/Kivy/Clock/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2/obj/local/arm64-v8a '
export LDLIBS='-lm'
export CC='/home/ve111/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target aarch64-linux-android21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a'
export CXX='/home/ve111/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ -target aarch64-linux-android21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a'
export AR='aarch64-linux-android-ar'
export RANLIB='aarch64-linux-android-ranlib'
export STRIP='aarch64-linux-android-strip --strip-unneeded'
export MAKE='make -j2'
export READELF='aarch64-linux-android-readelf'
export NM='aarch64-linux-android-nm'
export LD='aarch64-linux-android-ld'
export ARCH='arm64-v8a'
export NDK_API='android-21'
export TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX='aarch64-linux-android'
export TOOLCHAIN_VERSION='4.9'
export LDSHARED='/home/ve111/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target aarch64-linux-android21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -shared'
export BUILDLIB_PATH='/home/ve111/Kivy/Clock/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8'
export PATH='/home/ve111/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin:/home/ve111/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/:/home/ve111/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/:/home/ve111/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c:/home/ve111/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools:/home/ve111/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/:/home/ve111/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/:/home/ve111/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c:/home/ve111/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools:/home/ve111/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
export PYTHONNOUSERSITE='1'
export LANG='en_GB.UTF-8'
export PYTHONPATH='/home/ve111/Kivy/Clock/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/Lib:/home/ve111/Kivy/Clock/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/Lib/site-packages:/home/ve111/Kivy/Clock/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8:/home/ve111/Kivy/Clock/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/build/scripts-3.8:/home/ve111/Kivy/Clock/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8'
export LIBLINK='NOTNONE'
export NDKPLATFORM='/home/ve111/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot'
export COPYLIBS='1'
export LIBLINK_PATH='/home/ve111/Kivy/Clock/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/pyjnius-sdl2/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/objects_pyjnius'

[INFO]:    COMMAND:
cd /home/ve111/Kivy/Clock/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/pyjnius-sdl2/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/pyjnius && /home/ve111/Kivy/Clock/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 setup.py build_ext -v

[WARNING]: ERROR: /home/ve111/Kivy/Clock/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 failed!

# Command failed: /usr/local/bin/python3.7 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=time_tars --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch arm64-v8a --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/ve111/Kivy/Clock/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py --debug
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     XDG_VTNR = '7'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = 'c2'
#     CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR = '/var/lib/lightdm-data/ve111'
#     SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/home/ve111/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     VTE_VERSION = '4205'
#     QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON = '1'
#     WINDOWID = '60817418'
#     UPSTART_SESSION = 'unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1494'
#     GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL = ''
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge:unity-gtk-module'
#     USER = 've111'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     XDG_SESSION_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0'
#     XDG_SEAT_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/tars:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1786,unix/tars:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1786'
#     DEFAULTS_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg'
#     PATH = '/home/ve111/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME = 'appmenu-qt5'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     JOB = 'dbus'
#     PWD = '/home/ve111/Kivy/Clock'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     GNOME_KEYRING_PID = ''
#     LANG = 'en_IN'
#     GDM_LANG = 'en_US'
#     MANDATORY_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
#     COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE = 'ubuntu'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     SESSIONTYPE = 'gnome-session'
#     GTK2_MODULES = 'overlay-scrollbar'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     HOME = '/home/ve111'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     LANGUAGE = 'en_IN:en'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     LOGNAME = 've111'
#     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-X5cHiFazZM'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     INSTANCE = ''
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'Unity'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/home/ve111/.Xauthority'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/ve111'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/ve111/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/ve111/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/ve111/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I have also updated cython. In a question, someone suggests that I have installed cython3 and it was calling for cython. So I modified such that whenever cython is called , it is actually cython3. But this also didn't solve the error.

Comment: you probably have a bunch of old .c files generated by a previous version of Cython. You should delete those so that they get regenerated by the recent version of Cython you have installed

Comment: @DavidW Could you tell me how can I do it?

Comment: No. I don't know any of Kivy, Android, or bulldozer